# ffmpeg-filters, как заблюрить фон?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

Благодоря этому набору параметров, блюрится вырезанная картинка по середине.
Подскажите, как инвертировать блюр, и отблюрить наоборот, края по бокам?
P.S. Исходное разрешение видео: 1280 × 720

```
#! /bin/sh

ffmpeg -y -i orig.m4v -filter_complex "
[0:v]split[0v1][0v2];

[0v1]crop=720:720:280:0,
avgblur=sizeX=100[b];

[0v2][b]overlay=280:0[v]
" -map '[v]' -an output.mov
```